# error compiling libstdc++ for cortexa8hf-vfp "cannot compute sizeof (long long)

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, arm

I'm in the process of building python-openzwave for my arm device and part of the process is building libstdc++. Running configure works perfectly but upon running make I receive the error:

> configure: error: cannot compute sizeof (long long).

I'm including output of config.log as I don't know what else is needed to diagnose the issue. See link below.

[config.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o2ixfca2it1tnet/config.log?dl=0)

Comment: I think you have an issue defining --build/--host/--target in the command line.

Comment: Could you supply what commandline you used config?

Comment: I see in the config.log that:
`--build=x86_64-linux --host=arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi --target=arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi` which indicates host and target are the same, which I assume this is the case. Could you try to do the build on 32-bit machine (or VM)? It might be a toolchain issue.

Comment: Also, I wonder are you targetting big-endian ARM machine?

Comment: I've been attempting to built natively on my ARM machine so am not passing anything on the command line beyond calling ./configure and then make.  Of course now I wish I'd  --build=x86_64-linux as the machine is an armv7l and so only 32-bit.

Comment: Just to to be sure, are you building native on an ARM machine?

Comment: If you are building the library on ARM itself, then I think there is a problem in the config of this lib, it sees the build machine as `--build=x86_64-linux` which is wrong.
Repeat with this config command line:
`./configure --build=arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi --host=arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi --target=arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi` Please update me how it goes.